# Accesing dictionaries that are in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a list of dictionaries that are composed of key pairs, maybe even a dictionary of dictionaries added to a list, so

```
food = "apple"
taste = "sweet"
dict1 = {}
dict1[food] = sweet
list1 = []
list1.append(dict1)
```

in this way I'm thinking to use a loop to build up the list of dictionaries, and be able to sort the list by the keys or values in those dictionaries for example. But I can't find the syntax of how to retrieve information from the dictionaries in the list1, let alone sort them. I find this idea fiddly because I need to assess the whole list first rather than (for example) remove an item from the end of the list and then do stuff to it. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Create distionaries `{"apple":{"taste":"sweet"}}` and add them to a list...

Comment: Will there be `dict2`? What about `list2`?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: Completely unclear what you are asking. Sample input and sample output please.

Comment: ok so after a few iterations list1 might look like this- [{"apples" : "sweet"}, {"sausages" : "savory"}, {"chilli" : "hot"}] and so on. Then I'd like to unpack the values from the dictionaries in list1 so I can compare them with something for example.

Comment: refer [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and [dictionary - learn python hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html)

Comment: @SamChancer: I think you need to run through a good Python tutorial; it sounds like you don't understand looping or indexing, and that's pretty basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you index the `list`, you get back the `dict` at that index, and can then do lookup immediately:

```
>>> list1[0][food]
'sweet'
```

Or you can iterate the `list` to access one by one:

```
>>> for fooddict in list1:
...     print(fooddict)
{'apple': 'sweet'}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.:-)